# How can I allow all setRequestHeader in Ajax?

Tags: javascript

I am developing an application where I would like to allow my `setRequestHeader` to accept all file types. I'm trying to send via `POST` two input values, one of the text type and the other of the file type, but I'm only allowing one of the two.

my code:

```
 var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xml.open("POST", url, true);
 xml.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'multipart/form-data');
 //xml.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application\/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 xml.onloadend = response;
 xml.send(send);
```

How can I set the `setRequestHeader` to allow all file types or at least the ones I need which is text and file type, is there a specific setRequestHeader for that?

Comment: The [Accept header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation#server-driven_content_negotiation) informs the server which type of *response* the client will accept *from the server*. To send files you need `multipart/form-data` period.

Comment: Send a `FormData` instance... `const send = new FormData(); send.append("text", "some text"); send.append("file", fileInput.files[0]);`. See [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)